# How can i implement `MinimalBeaconProxy`?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, evm, assembly

I'm trying to make `MinimalBeaconProxy`. But seems like the assembly codes don't work. Can I get some advice of this codes?

#### Contracts

```js
contract BeaconProxyCreator {
    constructor(address beacon) payable {
        bytes20 beaconProxyAddr = bytes20(beacon);

        assembly {
            let ptr := mload(0x40)
            mstore(ptr, 0x635c60da1b6000526000806020600073)
            mstore(add(ptr, 0x10), beaconProxyAddr)
            mstore(add(ptr, 0x24), 0x5afa503d6000803e36600060203760008036602082515af43d6000803e60003d)
            mstore(add(ptr, 0x44), 0x91604957fd5bf3)
            return(add(0x00, ptr), 0x4a)
        }
    }
}
```

```js
contract BeaconProxyFactory {
    function deployBeaconProxy(address beacon) external returns (address deployed) {
        bytes memory creationCode =
            abi.encodePacked(type(BeaconProxyConstructor).creationCode, abi.encode(address(beacon)));

        uint256 nonce = 0;

        bytes32 salt;
        bool exist;

        while (true) {
            salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, nonce));

            deployed = address(
                uint160(
                    uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(bytes1(0xff), address(this), salt, keccak256(creationCode))))
                )
            );

            assembly {
                exist := gt(extcodesize(deployed), 0)
            }

            if (!exist) {
                break;
            }

            nonce++;
        }

        assembly {
            let data := add(0x20, creationCode)
            let size := mload(creationCode)
            deployed := create2(0, data, size, salt)

            if iszero(extcodesize(deployed)) {
                returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize())
                revert(0, returndatasize())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Decompilation

```js
contract Contract {
    function main() {
        memory[0x00:0x20] = 0x5c60da1b;
        memory[0x00:0x00] = address(0xdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef).staticcall.gas(msg.gas)(memory[0x00:0x20]);
        var temp0 = returndata.length;
        memory[0x00:0x00 + temp0] = returndata[0x00:0x00 + temp0];
        var temp1 = msg.data.length;
        memory[0x20:0x20 + temp1] = msg.data[0x00:0x00 + temp1];
        var temp2;
        temp2, memory[0x00:0x00] = address(memory[0x00:0x20]).delegatecall.gas(msg.gas)(memory[0x20:0x20 + msg.data.length]);
        var temp3 = returndata.length;
        memory[0x00:0x00 + temp3] = returndata[0x00:0x00 + temp3];
        var var1 = 0x00;
        var var0 = returndata.length;
    
        if (temp2) { return memory[var1:var1 + var0]; }
        else { revert(memory[var1:var1 + var0]); }
    }
}
```

#### Disassembly

```
    0000    63  PUSH4 0x5c60da1b
    0005    60  PUSH1 0x00
    0007    52  MSTORE
    0008    60  PUSH1 0x00
    000A    80  DUP1
    000B    60  PUSH1 0x20
    000D    60  PUSH1 0x00
    000F    73  PUSH20 {address}
    0024    5A  GAS
    0025    FA  STATICCALL
    0026    50  POP
    0027    3D  RETURNDATASIZE
    0028    60  PUSH1 0x00
    002A    80  DUP1
    002B    3E  RETURNDATACOPY
    002C    36  CALLDATASIZE
    002D    60  PUSH1 0x00
    002F    60  PUSH1 0x20
    0031    37  CALLDATACOPY
    0032    60  PUSH1 0x00
    0034    80  DUP1
    0035    36  CALLDATASIZE
    0036    60  PUSH1 0x20
    0038    82  DUP3
    0039    51  MLOAD
    003A    5A  GAS
    003B    F4  DELEGATECALL
    003C    3D  RETURNDATASIZE
    003D    60  PUSH1 0x00
    003F    80  DUP1
    0040    3E  RETURNDATACOPY
    0041    60  PUSH1 0x00
    0043    3D  RETURNDATASIZE
    0044    91  SWAP2
    0045    60  PUSH1 0x49
    0047    57  *JUMPI

label_0048:
    0048    FD  *REVERT

label_0049:
    0049    5B  JUMPDEST
    004A    F3  *RETURN
```

#### Test(forge)

```
Traces:
  [806813] BeaconDeployTest::test() 
    ├─ [0] VM::addr(<pk>) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0x7E5F4552091A69125d5DfCb7b8C2659029395Bdf
    ├─ [0] VM::addr(<pk>) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0x2B5AD5c4795c026514f8317c7a215E218DcCD6cF
    ├─ [98747] → new MockPoolImpl@0x5615dEB798BB3E4dFa0139dFa1b3D433Cc23b72f
    │   └─ ← 493 bytes of code
    ├─ [178396] → new UpgradableBeacon@0x2e234DAe75C793f67A35089C9d99245E1C58470b
    │   └─ ← 778 bytes of code
    ├─ [209738] → new BeaconProxyFactory@0xF62849F9A0B5Bf2913b396098F7c7019b51A820a
    │   └─ ← 937 bytes of code
    ├─ [0] VM::startPrank(0x2B5AD5c4795c026514f8317c7a215E218DcCD6cF) 
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [52202] BeaconProxyFactory::deployBeaconProxy(UpgradableBeacon: [0x2e234DAe75C793f67A35089C9d99245E1C58470b]) 
    │   ├─ [15088] → new <Unknown>@0x6E72539235FA5600EEb7322994FFEE453a5d2988
    │   │   └─ ← 74 bytes of code
    │   └─ ← 0x6E72539235FA5600EEb7322994FFEE453a5d2988
    ├─ [3466] UpgradableBeacon::implementation() [staticcall]
    │   ├─ [0] console::log(test) [staticcall]
    │   │   └─ ← ()
    │   └─ ← MockPoolImpl: [0x5615dEB798BB3E4dFa0139dFa1b3D433Cc23b72f]
    ├─ [0] console::log(0x0000000000000000000000005615deb798bb3e4dfa0139dfa1b3d433cc23b72f) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] 0x6E72539235FA5600EEb7322994FFEE453a5d2988::initialize(123) 
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] VM::stopPrank() 
    │   └─ ← ()
    └─ ← ()
```